# Use own map like Google map. Collect and process data when visitors click spots on map

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I am doing a website project related with travel. I think a long time, searching on the web for a long time. However I still have no idea how to get started. I really need help.

A brief description of my travel project first.

I need to use my own map. It can be zoomed in or zoomed out like Google Map. On the map there are many scenery spots, like spot A, spot B, spot C, etc....

When visitors open the map, click on the spots, for example, spot Y, spot A, spot M, etc.... I need to get which spots they clicked on, group all data, and finally write the data into MySQL database.

Here's what I find up to now:

I find many jQuery plugins and tools, like OpenLayers, mapTiler, mapBox, etc.. They all use Google Map, Open Street Map, and other maps, but not allow to use own map.

I also find Gmap Image Cutter which can cut my large map into tiles and display on the web. However the map cannot be clicked on get the data as required.

My questions:

I can master PHP and jQuery.

Could someone give me some idea how to get started?

Which tool or plugins can best accomplish my projects?

Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to do seems difficult. If you're trying to collect longitude and latitude from a click on the map and allow users to zoom and still collect map position, then you're gonna have to write a ton of code. That's why google maps and other maps are popular. Why do you have to use your own map? You can embed third-party maps within your website, and you can use google maps for free up to a certain quota per day. What you're trying to do would take months of work to accomplish.

Comment: `but not allow to use own map` what do you mean by **own map**? Is it place in the earth? you can display your own map using google-maps, you know?

Comment: I wish to use my own map because I wish to use a map that highlight with interested spots only. The Google Map has too much information I don't need.

Comment: Yes, I know I can display my own map using google-maps. Actually I have been using it for some years. I wish to use my own map that is much easier to use for my visitors.

Comment: Actually I am not trying to collect longitude and latitude from a click on the map. I will draw some spots on the map, for example, London, Wembley, Holloway, etc... I wish to get the name of the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps JavaScript API provides an OverlayView class for creating your own custom overlays.

Link to doc: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#subclass

Link to example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow

And last, but not least, Google Maps can be embedded into your website: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/

Comment: Hi Gjermund, Thanks for your information. The overlays seems a possible solution. However the overlay map is not clear when zoom in.

Comment: @Alex I don't have a lot of experience with overlays myself, I suggest you raise a new question for that.

Comment: You might want to look into the html `<map>` and `<area>` [tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map). These will allow you to define spots and shapes on the top of your map image. Click events on these spots & shapes can be bound to and managed by jQuery. There are also tools like http://www.image-maps.com that simplifies the code definitions.

Comment: Hi Gjermund, Yes, I can use the html <map> and <area> tags to define spots and shapes on the top of your map image. Since the big map is cut into many tiles and position into different layers. I have no idea how to get the layer number and the tile ID.

Comment: Gmap Image Cutter might not be the best answer - last update is 2 years old, clearly not being maintained. You could just go for one high definition image, using map/area tags to define points of interest.

Comment: Hi Gjermund, Thanks for your great help. You are really helpful. Yes, I am also thinking to use a big svg map to do that rather than stuck on this stage.